# Adding sample size to ggplot boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, boxplot, sample

I'm interested to see how age is related to a continuous outcome, for which I have the following data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)

mydata <- 
structure(list(ID = c(104, 157, 52, 152, 114, 221, 320, 125, 
75, 171, 80, 76, 258, 82, 142, 203, 37, 92, 202, 58, 194, 38, 
4, 137, 25, 87, 40, 117, 21, 255, 277, 315, 96, 134, 185, 94, 
3, 153, 172, 65, 279, 209, 60, 13, 154, 160, 24, 29, 159, 213, 
127, 74, 48, 126, 184, 132, 61, 141, 27, 49, 8, 39, 164, 162, 
34, 205, 179, 119, 77, 135, 138, 165, 103, 253, 14, 20, 310, 
84, 30, 273, 22, 105, 262, 116, 86, 83, 145, 31, 95, 51, 81, 
271, 36, 50, 189, 2, 115, 7, 197, 54), age = c(67.1, 70.7, 53, 
61.7, 66.1, 57.7, 54.1, 67.2, 60.9, 55.8, 40.7, 57.6, 64.1, 70.7, 
47.5, 46.3, 66.7, 55, 63.3, 68.2, 61.2, 60.5, 52, 65.3, 48.9, 
56.9, 62.7, 75.2, 61.4, 57.9, 53.6, 58.1, 51, 67.3, 63.9, 57, 
43.2, 64.7, 62.8, 56.3, 51.7, 39.4, 45.2, 57.8, 55.7, 69.6, 61.5, 
50.1, 73.7, 55.5, 65.2, 54.6, 49, 35.2, 52.9, 46.3, 55, 52.5, 
54.2, 61, 57.4, 56.5, 53.6, 47.7, 64.2, 53.4, 60.9, 58.2, 60.7, 
50.3, 48.3, 74.7, 52.1, 59.9, 52.4, 70.8, 61.2, 66.5, 55.4, 57.5, 
59.2, 60.1, 52.3, 60.2, 54.8, 36.3, 61.5, 48.6, 56, 62, 64.8, 
40.4, 68.3, 60, 69.1, 56.6, 45.3, 58.5, 52.3, 52), continuous_outcome = c(3636.6, 
1128.2, 2007.5, 802.9, 332.3, 2636.1, 169.5, 67.9, 3261.8, 1920.3, 
155.2, 1677.2, 198.2, 11189.7, 560.9, 633.1, 196.1, 13.9, 100.7, 
7594.5, 1039.8, 83.9, 2646.8, 284.6, 306, 1135.6, 1883.1, 5681.4, 
1706.2, 2241.1, 97.7, 1106.8, 1107.1, 290.8, 2123.4, 267, 115.3, 
138.5, 152.7, 1338.9, 6709.8, 561.7, 1931.7, 3112.4, 1876.3, 
3795.9, 5706.7, 7.4, 1324.9, 4095.4, 205.4, 1886, 177.3, 304.4, 
1319.1, 415.9, 537.2, 3141.1, 740, 1976.7, 624.8, 983.1, 1163.5, 
1432.6, 3730.4, 2023.4, 498.2, 652.5, 982.7, 1345.3, 138.4, 1505.1, 
3528.1, 11.9, 884.5, 10661.6, 1911.4, 2800.8, 81.5, 396.4, 409.1, 
417.3, 186, 1892.4, 1689.7, 0, 210.1, 210.5, 3484.5, 3196.8, 
57.2, 20.2, 947, 540, 1603.1, 1571.8, 9.1, 149.2, 122, 63.2), 
    age_decades = structure(c(3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

To make a boxplot of age decades on the x axis and my continuous outcome I'm using `ggplot2`.
I want to make several, and automatically plot the sample size on the x-axis ticks. To do so I've computed labels in the dataset as follows:

```
mydata <- 
  mydata %>% 
  group_by(age_decades) %>% 
  mutate(n_decades=as_character(n())) %>% 
  mutate(label_decades=case_when(age_decades==1 ~ "Below 50", 
                                 age_decades==2 ~ "Between 50 and 60", 
                                 age_decades==3 ~ "Between 60 and 70", 
                                 age_decades==4 ~ "Above 70")) %>% 
  mutate(label_decades=paste0(label_decades, '\n n = ', n_decades)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  relocate(age_decades, label_decades, .after=age) %>% 
  select(-n_decades) %>% 
  arrange(ID)
```

Then I've tried to plot the boxplot using the newly created variable label_decades to label. The first thing I tried was:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=age_decades, y=continuous_outcome)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels=mydata$label_decades)
```

But that just plots the first few labels as they occur in the dataset (so they dont correspond to the actual boxplot):

[image]

Then I tried:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=age_decades, y=continuous_outcome)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_text(data=mydata, aes(age_decades, Inf, label=label_decades), 
            vjust = 15, size=4)
```

[image]

Which works better but the font is really weird and also the original x axis labels/ticks are still showing.
Anyone know how to solve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: you also want to put label Like the one in the last plot along with "n"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font looks wired because there are many labels with the same text plotted on top of each other. You can use `distinct` to get only one label per x tick and use the `theme` function to get rid of x tick labels:

```
mydata %>%
  ggplot(aes(age_decades, continuous_outcome)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    geom_text(
      data = mydata %>% distinct(age_decades, label_decades),
      mapping = aes(label = label_decades),
      y = 9e3
    ) +
    theme(
      axis.text.x = element_blank()
    )
```

Comment: Thanks @danlooo very much for your answer. 
As a follow-up question: what does the `y=9e3` part of your code within the `geom_text` do exactly?

Comment: Overwrite the y value to 9*10^3=9000 to put all labels in the same height

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to turn the labels to factor as well.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mydata <- mydata %>% 
  group_by(age_decades) %>% 
  mutate(n_decades= as.character(n())) %>% 
  mutate(label_decades= case_when(age_decades==1 ~ "Below 50", 
                                 age_decades==2 ~ "Between 50 and 60", 
                                 age_decades==3 ~ "Between 60 and 70", 
                                 age_decades==4 ~ "Above 70")) %>% 
  mutate(label_decades= factor(paste0(label_decades, '\n n = ', n_decades))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  relocate(age_decades, label_decades, .after=age) %>% 
  select(-n_decades) %>% 
  arrange(ID)
```

You can then use it's `levels` in `scale_x_discrete`.

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=age_decades, y=continuous_outcome)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels= levels(mydata$label_decades))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @RonakShah. Would you by any chance also know how to plot the median values a set value above the line for the median per boxplot? As in, for the first boxplot for example plot the value of the median 5mm above the line indicating that value?
Thanks!